# What is the correct way to save state back to database in AngularJS?

Tags: rest, angularjs

The last example on the Angular homepage shows state being saved to a Mongo database using the mongolab API, however the API key is in the JavaScript file and easily viewable by the client. My question is what is the correct way to securely communicate with the server side rest API using Angular?

Comment: The way you communicate with the server should not change when you use angular. Angular does not prescribe how the server is structured, or how it operates. Though it prefers a REST api, not even that is necessary. However you communicated with the server securely before is the same way you should continue to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle the security to use 3rd-party's restful store api, with js mvc framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345282/how-to-handle-the-security-to-use-3rd-partys-restful-store-api-with-js-mvc-fra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a pretty standard strategy is to run the API on the same domain as the AngularJS app (to prevent cross domain issues)

so for example the routes for the entire app (backend + frontend) can be:

/ - frontend AngularJS app,

/api - rest API

the next step is authentication and authorization, this can be done with sessions.
so when someone is accessing /api you know which user is it and if he is permitted to do so.

just to be clear - don't access Mongo directly from the frontend app, build an API for this.